# unique_ptr as a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, unique-ptr

Why does this compile in VS 2017?

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct x 
{
    x()  { cout << "x()" << endl; }
    ~x() { cout << "~x()" << endl; }
};

template <typename T>
void foo(T&& item)
{
    struct boo 
    {
        T item;

        boo(T&& t)
            : item(std::move(t))
        { }
    };

    new boo(std::move(item));
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<x> b(new x);

    foo(b); // I would expect that I should put std::move(b) here.
}
```

With the code as written, the output is

```
x()
~x()
```

If the `foo(b)` line were written as `foo(std::move(b))`, then the output is simply

```
x()
```

i.e. the instance of `x` is leaked.  I would expect the code as written to be a compiler error, since it seems like the `unique_ptr<x>` is copied at the call to `foo`?

Comment: `T&&` is a reference, why would you expect a copy?

Comment: I thought an explicit `std::move` is needed to create a `T&&`.  Anyway, I'm simply confused because the instance of `x` is being deleted when this test case is designed to try to leak it.

Comment: "I thought an explicit std::move is needed to create a T&&" I think you're confused by the difference between rvalue-references and universal references.

Comment: Maybe you tested that yourself, but clang6 and gcc 8 don't compile without the cast to an rvalue of `b`  in `main` and the instantiation of `boo` does indeed leak memory.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed it doesn't compile there.  I wonder if it's a bug in the VC++ compiler.

Comment: Looks like a bug, fixed in VC++2017 with permissive- flag (then VC++ also generates an error): https://godbolt.org/g/rfqtis

Comment: @AdamF Interesting.  I see that `permissive-` fixes it.  However, if I take MarekR's advice and change the `move` to `forward`, it compiles happily even with `permissive-` :(.

Comment: Since the parameter `item` of `foo` is a "forwarding reference" aka "universal reference", `T` is `std::unique_ptr<x>&` (not `std::unique_ptr<x>`).  The program is still ill-formed, but the error is with attempting to initialize reference member `std::unique_ptr<x>& item;` with the xvalue `std::move(t)` in the `boo` constructor, not at the statement `foo(b);`.

Comment: Its not a bug. It's an extension that pops up from time to time. VC allows binding rvalues to lvalue references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When clang is used it doesn't compile: https://wandbox.org/permlink/HCIDXxS1yqyq7uCb
And it works with Visual Studio: http://rextester.com/GUR47187

So it looks like a bug in VS.

It always works with `move`: https://wandbox.org/permlink/u3N06Idr8ELo9SIp

Also in case of templates `std::forward` [should be used](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CNndZSYzwRwg7sN8) instead `std::move`.

[Here is code](http://rextester.com/VQOG37779) which finds how VS resolves templates:

```
void __cdecl foo<classstd::unique_ptr<struct x,struct std::default_delete<struct x> >&>(class std::unique_ptr<struct x,struct std::default_delete<struct x> > &)
```

So `unique_ptr` is not moved just passed by reference to `unique_ptr`.